# oracle database connectivity using c language

Tags: c, oracle

I would like to connect to the an Oracle database using c language. For that I use the oOacle precompiler and my os is ubuntu 11.04.

My code is

```
 #include<stdlib.h>
 #include "/home/prasad/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/precomp/public/sqlca.h"
 int var1;
 EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;
 VARCHAR ENAME[10];
 int dno;
 EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION;
 main()
 {
     EXEC SQL CONNECT :SCOTT IDENTIFIED BY :TIGER;
     printf("\nConnected to ORACLE as user: \n");

 }
```

I compiled this using the precompiler but it gives the error

> PCC-F-02044, CMD-LINE:  Illegal or out of range value for option:  ltype=long

What is the problem?

Comment: which line has the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Since the error refers to the command line and [`ltype` is a command-line flag](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10825/pc_10opt.htm#sthref1642), this indicates it probably isn't getting as far as looking at your code.

If you aren't specifying the flag on the command line, check the settings in the configuration file - the banner for `proc` shows where that is in a message saying 'System default option values taken from ...'. In your case I'd guess that would be `/home/prasad/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/precomp/admin/pcscfg.cfg`.

Assuming that explicitly has it set to `long`, you could try just adding `ltype=short` to your `proc` command, and if that works then maybe change it in the `pcscfg.cfg` file to make life easier later. If that doesn't help, add your entire `proc` command and the contents of that file to your question.

As far as I'm aware Ubuntu isn't a supported platform for Oracle so it's also possible this just won't work, though that seems unlikely...